# How do I stop this PermissionError: [WinErr32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another file?

Tags: python, jupyter

[image]

How can I stop the other process(created by the python without my knowing) not to block my access to my file or how can I give permission access to my Python script?

I am trying to use a .get_feature method on a molecule's xyz file that is already instantiated into a mol3D class (molsimplify) on Jupyter. Only for me to get this error:

> permission error: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\Users\User\Appdata\local\Temp\tmpdv35q8xf.xyz'

Comment: What file are you trying to delete here?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: I am not trying to delete any file. I am trying to use a .get_feature method on a molecule's xyz file that is already instantiated into a mol3D class (molsimplify) on jupyter. Only for me to get this error "permission error: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\Users\\User\\Appdata\\local\\Temp\\tmpdv35q8xf.xyz'.